# python datetime to string to plug into linear regression equation

Tags: python, datetime

I  believe I need to convert datetime to a string so I can plug this variable into my linear equation

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

x = datetime.datetime.strptime(now.astype(str).str[:10], '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal()
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

or

> ValueError: unconverted data remains:  18:17:27.424685
> when I try

```
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(now), '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal()
```

or

> AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'astype'
> when I try

```
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(now.astype(str).str[:10], '%Y-%m-%d').toordinal()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` is a function that converts a string into a datetime object, you have a datetime object already, and you are trying to convert it to a string and back to a datetime object, this is not needed.

My guess is that you are trying to remove the time component of the datetime object in order to get the ordinal of the date, you can more easily do it this way:

```
now.date().toordinal()
```

But since `toordinal()` disregards the time component anyway doing the following will yield the same result:

```
now.toordinal()
```

Comment: perfect, that worked